# Grouping by multiple columns to find duplicate rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I have a `df`

```
id    val1     val2
 1     1.1      2.2
 1     1.1      2.2
 2     2.1      5.5
 3     8.8      6.2
 4     1.1      2.2
 5     8.8      6.2
```

I want to group by `val1 and val2` and get similar dataframe only with rows which has multiple occurrence of same `val1 and val2` combination.

Final `df`:

```
id    val1     val2
 1     1.1      2.2
 4     1.1      2.2
 3     8.8      6.2
 5     8.8      6.2
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with parameter `subset` for specify columns for check with `keep=False` for all duplicates for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['val1','val2'], keep=False)]
print (df)
   id  val1  val2
0   1   1.1   2.2
1   1   1.1   2.2
3   3   8.8   6.2
4   4   1.1   2.2
5   5   8.8   6.2
```

Detail:

```
print (df.duplicated(subset=['val1','val2'], keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: How can I find group these? I need to group ids [0,1,4] as they have same data.

Comment: @VenkataGogu - Use `df.groupby('val1')`

Comment: @jezrael do you mean to `groupby` before or after the `duplicated`? Can you please add this to your answer?

Comment: @KLaz - Do you need `df.groupby(['val1','val2'])['id'].agg(list).reset_index(name='new')` ?

Comment: @Klaz @VenkataGogu I'd directly use this: ``` df = df[df['val1', 'val2'].duplicated() == True].reset_index(drop=True) ``` if I want to create a dataframe having them grouped by

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to compute the size of groups and only keep the rows whose group is larger than 1.

```py
msk = df.groupby(['val1', 'val2'])['val1'].transform('size') > 1
df1 = df[msk]
```

[image: res]