# Finding duplicate rows (combinations) and merge and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe like this:

```
data = {'From': ['1', '1', '2', '2'],
        'To': ['2', '4', '1', '7'],
        'Total': [100, 100, 100, 100]
        }

dataf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['From', 'To', 'Total'])
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

The first and third row are duplicated, but just in a different order i.e. (1,2) and (2,1).

I want to remove the duplicated rows, but sum the values onto which ever row is left.

i.e. the table would look like this:

[image]

I have found posts that discuss how to remove duplications that are in any column order (eg. [Grouping by multiple columns to find duplicate rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640945/grouping-by-multiple-columns-to-find-duplicate-rows-pandas)), but nothing about how to sum the values before removing.

Comment: I was ready to post an answer that gets you the result, right before it was closed. Let me know if you need it, it works.

Comment: Thank you sophods, going to check Marias answer and will let you know if I do :) edit: Marias answer does what I need. Thank you for your offer of help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating some key for grouping and summing:

```
dataf['key'] = dataf.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted((row['From'], row['To']))), axis=1)
dataf = dataf.groupby('key')['Total'].sum().reset_index()
dataf['From'] = dataf['key'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
dataf['To'] = dataf['key'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
del dataf['key']
```