# Finding Duplicates based on equal values in multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datatable

I used pandas to get a list of all Email duplicates, but not all email duplicates are in fact duplicates of a contact, because the company may be small, so that all employees have the same email-address for example.

| Email | FirstName | LastName | Phone | Mobile | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a@company-a.com | John | Doe | 12342 | 65464 | Company_a |
| a@company-a.com | John | Doe | 43214 | 45645 | Comp_ny A |
| a@company-a.com | Adam | Smith | 34223 | 46456 | Company A |
| b@company-b.com | Bill | Gates | 23423 | 63453 | Company B |
| b@company-b.com | Bill | Gates | 32421 | 43244 | Comp B |
| b@company-b.com | Elon | Musk | 42342 | 34234 | Company B |

That's why I came up with the following condition to filter my Email duplicate list further down:

I want to extract all the cases where the Email, FirstName and LastName are equal in a dataframe because that almost certainly would mean that this is a real duplicate. The extracted dataframe should look like this in the end:

| Email | FirstName | LastName | Phone | Mobile | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a@company-a.com | John | Doe | 12342 | 65464 | Company_a |
| a@company-a.com | John | Doe | 43214 | 45645 | Comp_ny A |
| b@company-b.com | Bill | Gates | 23423 | 63453 | Company B |
| b@company-b.com | Bill | Gates | 32421 | 43244 | Comp B |

How can I get there? Is it possible to check for multiple equal conditions?

I would appreciate any feedback regarding the best practices.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping by multiple columns to find duplicate rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640945/grouping-by-multiple-columns-to-find-duplicate-rows-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.drop_duplicates`

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName'], keep='first')
```

output

```
Email   FirstName   LastName    Phone   Mobile  Company
0   a@company-a.com John    Doe 12342   65464   Company_a
2   a@company-a.com Adam    Smith   34223   46456   Company A
3   b@company-b.com Bill    Gates   23423   63453   Company B
5   b@company-b.com Elon    Musk    42342   34234   Company B
```

To get the duplicates

```
df[~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName'], keep='first').index)]
```

output

```
Email   FirstName   LastName    Phone   Mobile  Company
1   a@company-a.com John    Doe 43214   45645   Comp_ny A
4   b@company-b.com Bill    Gates   32421   43244   Comp B
```