# Efficient way to find connected ticket validations in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The thing is that I currently have a pandas dataframe (which I am going to denote by `validations` with the following columns

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| line | orientation | route | validationDate | cardNumber | stop |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1  |     2       |  2    |1994-01-18,18:00| O219838111 | 2393 |
|   1  |     1       |  1    |1994-01-18,18:03| O211233111 | 2400 |
|  ... |    ...      | ...   |      ...       |     ...    |  ... |
```

My **goal** is to find all validations that are *connected*, that is: look for pairs of entries with the same `cardNumber` that have taken place during the same day, regardless of whether it took place on the same line, orientation, bus stop or route.

The thing is that my "grouping" skills are a bit limited so I haven't come up with a better solution than to use one big loop using

```
itertools.product(validations.iterrows(), validations.iterrows())
```

But as expected this simply takes too long.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! It would be really helpful if you can edit your question to include sample input and expected output. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please see the following link: [Grouping by multiple columns to find duplicate rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640945/grouping-by-multiple-columns-to-find-duplicate-rows-pandas)